# .Submit() not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, form-submit

I have a from skeleton like below

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Preapprove", "Preapproval", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "form1", id = "form1", enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
  ......
<input name="submit" type="button" value="Submit" id="Sub" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left:950px" />                     


 }
```

And in jquery im submitting this form on the click even of the button id Sub

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Sub').click(function (e) {
              var error_flag = 0;

                if (d_row_count == 1) {
                    error_flag = 1;
                }
                else if (d_row_count > 1) {
                    if (code == null || code.trim() == '') {
                        error_flag = 1;

                    }
                    else if (s_row_count == 1) {
                        error_flag = 1;
                    }
                }
                if (error_flag != 1) {
                    alert("submitting");
                    $("#form1").submit();
                 }
            });
```

When all the validation passed the error_flag will be 0 and it is getting inside the if condition and giving me the alert  "Submitting" but the form is not getting submitted.

Anything im missing on the code?

Comment: what does the **console** say?

Comment: it give the alert "submitting" and stay on the page. No other msgs

Comment: Try `alert("submitting: " + $("#form1").length);` and verify that it shows "submitting: 1". Then try to `alert("submitting: " + $("#form1")[0].tagName);` and verify that it shows "submitting: FORM".

Comment: Dear John..I changed the alert accordingly. First one give me "submitting: 1" and second one gave the result "submitting: FORM"

Comment: That all looks good. Try changing `$("#form1").submit();` to `$("#form1")[0].submit();`. That will call the form element's `submit()` method directly, without calling any submit-event handler bound to the form. You shouldn't have to do this, but perhaps there is a submit-handler that is preventing the form from submitting.

Comment: I already tried the same but no luck :(

Comment: Try changing the name of the button to something other than "submit". It may seem strange, but I think that can cause this to fail.

Comment: Dear John, Like u said it seems strange.. i changed the name from "submit" and it got worked. Thanks..

Comment: I added that as answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to change the name of the input button from "submit" to something else. Having an element named "submit" causes the form's submit method to no longer work, which means the form cannot be submitted via JavaScript (at least, not easily).

The reason for this is because an input element named "submit" can be referenced by its name like this: `form1.submit`. That is, the input element is added as a property of the form object, with the property name being the name of the input element. That basically hides the `submit` function that is on the form's prototype.

---

I say "not easily" above, because the following still works (at least in Firefox):

```
HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call($("#form1")[0]);
```

Comment: I spent half an hour trying to figure out what was wrong with my form. This solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can capture the form's native submit event, and then center the JavaScript code around the form's submit method, rather than the click event of the button.

The button needs to have a type of `submit` (clicking a button that has `type=submit` naturally triggers the event).

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" id="Sub" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left:950px" />
```

And then for your JavaScript.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form1").submit(function (e) {

        if (d_row_count == 1) {
            return;
        }
        else if (d_row_count > 1) {
            if (code == null || code.trim() == '') {
                return;

            }
            else if (s_row_count == 1) {
                return;
            }
        }

        // Thre were no errors!
        alert("submitting");

        // If you want to override the form submit method completely, use...
        // e.preventDefault();

    });
});
```